# Eloquent: filter both pivot table and model table

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

Eloquent relationship as below:

"stores" belongs to many "storedaytimes" (belong to many)

The pivot table (store_day_time_stores) has a key called "user_id", the storedaytimes table has a field called "date".

I want to filter records in "storedaytimes" based on given "user_id(from pivot table)" and a "start" and "end" date(from storedaytime table).

My current query is

```
$storedaytime->stores()
    ->wherePivot('user_id','=',$user)
    ->orderBy('date')
    ->where('date','>=',$start)
    ->where('date','<=',$end)->get();
```

It's producing a very scary looking query that's not working:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'date' in
>   'where clause' (SQL: select `stores`.*,
>   `order_day_time_store`.`order_day_time_id` as
>   `pivot_order_day_time_id`, `order_day_time_store`.`store_id` as
>   `pivot_store_id`, `order_day_time_store`.`user_id` as `pivot_user_id`,
>   `order_day_time_store`.`id` as `pivot_id` from `stores` inner join
>   `order_day_time_store` on `stores`.`id` =
>   `order_day_time_store`.`store_id` where
>   `order_day_time_store`.`order_day_time_id` is null and
>   `order_day_time_store`.`user_id` = 4 and `date` >= 2017-05-01 12:00:00
>   and `date` <= 2017-05-31 12:00:00 order by `date` asc)

Please help.thank you :3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured out myself: the following query works:

```
$storedaytime ->where('date','>=',$start)
->where('date','<=',$end)
->whereHas('stores',function($q) use($user){
                $q->where('user_id',$user);})
->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$storedaytime->stores()
    ->wherePivot('user_id','=',$user)
    ->whereBetween('storedaytimes.date', [$start, $end])
    ->orderBy('storedaytimes.date')
    ->get();
```

It is recommended that the order by clause be at the end of SQL statements, unless you have to order the date beforehand. There is no reason to do it in your case, so place it at the end.

Comment: noted re order. this doesn't work, it gives this error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'order_day_time_store.order_day_time_store.user_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select `stores`.*, `order_day_time_store`.`order_day_time_id` as `pivot_order_day_time_id`, `order_day_time_store`.`store_id` as `pivot_store_id`, `order_day_time_store`.`user_id` as `pivot_user_id`, `order_day_time_store`.`id` as `pivot_id` from `stores` inner join `order_day_time_store` on `stores`.`id` = `order_day_time_store`.`store_id` where `order_day_time_store`.`order_day_time_id` is null and

Comment: Ok then remove the 'store_day_time_stores' from the wherePivot clause